# python: pysftp only download first 10MB and exit

Tags: python

I am using pysftp to download files from server.

I am debugging my code. For that purpose i want pysftp to download only 10MB and exit.

```
    sftp_folder_location = 'outbound'
    sftp = pysftp.Connection(host=Hostname, username=Username, password=Password,cnopts=cnopts)
    with sftp.cd(sftp_folder_location):
        local_path = '/home/ubuntu/data'
        sftp.isfile(filename)
        sftp.get(filename,os.path.join(local_path, filename))
    sftp.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

To limit the file download size to 10MB, you can use the getfo method of the pysftp.Connection object along with urllib.request.urlopen to open the file and read only the first 10MB of data. Here's an example code:

```
import urllib.request

sftp_folder_location = 'outbound'
sftp = pysftp.Connection(host=Hostname, username=Username, password=Password, cnopts=cnopts)
with sftp.cd(sftp_folder_location):
    filename = 'example.txt'
    remote_path = sftp.normalize('example.txt')
    local_path = '/home/ubuntu/data'
    with sftp.open(remote_path, 'r') as remote_file:
        with open(os.path.join(local_path, filename), 'wb') as local_file:
            data = remote_file.read(1024*1024*10) # read only 10MB of data
            local_file.write(data)

sftp.close()
```

In this example, the `sftp.open` method is used to open the remote file for reading, and then the `read` method is called on the resulting file object with an argument of `1024*1024*10` to read only the first `10MB` of data. The `with` statement is used to ensure that both the remote and local files are properly closed after the download is complete.